# lldb: `frame variable` has no value return

Tags: c++, node.js, electron, lldb

I use electron/build_tools to build electron and run `e init --root=~/electron --bootstrap testing; e debug`.(`e debug` runs local Electron build inside of lldb.)

Set a breakpoint by `(lldb) br set --file archive.cc --line 155`

Print any variable in this file, eg `p header` ,`p size` but return error.

Run `frame variable` , `frame variable -g` but no value return.

```
(lldb) br set --file archive.cc --line 155
(lldb) r
Process 30523 launched: '/Users/electron/src/out/Testing/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron' (x86_64)
Electron Framework was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
Process 30523 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100352d90 Electron Framework`::Init() at archive.cc:155:63 [opt]
   152    }
   153  
   154    base::PickleIterator header_pickle(
-> 155        base::Pickle(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(file_.data() + 8), size));
   156    std::string header;
   157    if (!header_pickle.ReadString(&header)) {
   158      LOG(ERROR) << "Failed to read header string at '" << path_.value() << "'";
Target 0: (Electron) stopped.
(lldb) frame variable
(lldb) p file_
error: <user expression 21>:1:1: use of undeclared identifier 'file_'
file_
^
(lldb) p size
error: <user expression 23>:1:1: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
size
^~~~
note: possible target for call
```

Comment: I don't know how you would do this using Electron, but you might see if you can build this code unoptimized.  Optimizers have a bad habit of not tracking variables well as they are optimizing the use of them.  That's why lldb puts up that warning when it stops in a frame that was built with optimization on.

Comment: tks,that's correct! I found I need to set a compilation parameter.